# aptitude update gives 404's for intrepid

Tags: server, package-management, aptitude, updates, 8.10

I'm having issues trying to update my packages. I haven't used this server since last September and now I'm getting 404 errors on all the intrepid repos. How do I fix this?

Thanks

aptitude update

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com intrepid-security/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com intrepid-security/restricted Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com intrepid-security/main Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com intrepid-security/restricted Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com intrepid-security/universe Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com intrepid-security/universe Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid-updates/multiverse Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid-updates/multiverse Sources
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid/restricted Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid/main Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com intrepid-security/multiverse Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid/restricted Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid/universe Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid/universe Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid/multiverse Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid/multiverse Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid-updates/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com intrepid-security/multiverse Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid-updates/restricted Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid-updates/main Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid-updates/restricted Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid-updates/universe Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid-updates/universe Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid-updates/multiverse Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com intrepid-updates/multiverse Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Reading package lists...
```

sources.list

```
# 
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 8.10 _Intrepid Ibex_ - Release i386 (20081028.1)]/ intrepid main restricted

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 8.10 _Intrepid Ibex_ - Release i386 (20081028.1)]/ intrepid main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository. This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is
## offered by Canonical and the respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu
## users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu intrepid partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu intrepid partner

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-security main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-security universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-security multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-security multiverse
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Intrepid (8.10) was not a Long Term Support release and I believe support for it was dropped as of April 2010. It's most likely that Canonical has removed the old repos for Intrepid. To "fix" this issue, you should consider upgrading your installation to a newer version of Ubuntu, either the Maverick Meerkat (most current version, 10.10) or Lucid Lynx (the most current Long Term Support release, 10.04).

Comment: I did the sequential upgrade (`do-release-upgrade` 3 times) and now I look back and wonder if there was a better way to do that without completely re-installing?

Comment: @dotjoe Given the version of Ubuntu you were on, I don't think there was a better way. If this machine is one that you don't plan on upgrading often and don't need the latest/greatest software on, you should consider sticking to the LTS releases as you can upgrade from one LTS directly to the next (without loading all the intervening releases). For example, if your machine had still been on 8.04 (Hardy Heron) you could have following these instructions to go direct to Lucid Lynx https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LucidUpgrades#Upgrade from 8.04 LTS to 10.04 LTS

Comment: Cool. Thanks for that link. I'm sticking to LTS from now on.